# I can't understand scopedSlots of the vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am a beginner of the vue.js. I can't understand scopedSlots and example in the [guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots).Can you give me a detailed answer，thanks very much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through the help-center [help], in particular "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" [help/dont-ask], and "What topics can I ask about here?" [help/on-topic]. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on Stack Overflow, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers!

Comment: watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWdOucfAzTo

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to illustrate with an example using plain JavaScript functions.

Think of the component like a function, eg

```js
function todoList(todos) {
  // render <ul>, loop todos, render <li> and todo.text
}
```

Now imagine that function is able to be passed an optional content rendering function named `slot`

```js
function todoList(todos, slot) {
  slot = slot || slotProps => {
    // render slotProps.todo.text
  }

  // render <ul>

  todos.forEach(todo => {
    // render <li>

    slot({ todo }) // call "slot" function
  }
}
```

That function assigned to `slot` is the equivalent of

```html
<slot v-bind:todo="todo">
  <!-- Fallback content -->
  {{ todo.text }}
</slot>
```

from the example.

So now when you call this function, you can optionally use something like

```js
todoList(todos, slotProps => {
  if (slotProps.todo.isCompleted) {
    // render a checkmark, eg ✓
  }
  // render slotProps.todo.text
})
```

The function passed in here is the equivalent of

```html
<template slot-scope="slotProps">
  <!-- Define a custom template for todo items, using -->
  <!-- `slotProps` to customize each todo.            -->
  <span v-if="slotProps.todo.isComplete">✓</span>
  {{ slotProps.todo.text }}
</template>
```

in the example.